# Google sheets #VALUE! Error when sum value infinite

Tags: linux, google-sheets, spreadsheet

So, I have a Google sheets that is designed to keep track of flight hours and lots of other information about my flights. When I do a simple =SUM(J2:K) I get an error message #VALUE! But other computations with this same format work just fine. But when I do =SUM(J2:K1999) it provides the correct number. so I proceeded to delete all unused by selecting the column and unselecting the cells I’ve used, then deleting them. Yet I still get the error. Can someone please tell me what could be going on? I’d provide an screenshots of this project but it has sensitive info.

Uhh explained above, but tried limiting the value more, if =SUM(J2:K2000) is used it provides #VALUE! as well

Comment: So sum() will give an error when any of the cells contains defective data. Do sum(J2:J200) and sum(K2:K2000) and see if one or both contain errors. then narrow it down by sum(j2:J100) etc etc